# How to remove query string from current page URL?

Tags: hooks

On page load, I wanted to remove specific query string from the current URL, is that possible? Is there a specific function for that?

There is a function `remove_query_arg('query_key');` and `template_redirect`, I think I can use them, something like.

```
function abc_redirections() {
    $url = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (isset($_GET['query_string'])){
        if(empty($_GET['query_string']) || !is_numeric($_GET['query_string']) || $_GET['query_string'] < 1){
            $url = remove_query_arg('query_string', $url);
        }
    }
    if (isset($_GET['query_string_1'])){
        if(empty($_GET['query_string_1']) || !is_numeric($_GET['query_string_1']) || $_GET['query_string_1'] < 1){
            $url = remove_query_arg('query_string_1', $url);
        }
    }
    
    if(isset($_GET['query_string_1']) || isset($_GET['query_string_1'])){
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'abc_redirections' );
```

But it won't work, the page says "Page not working, redirected you too many times.". Something's not right with the condition. Also, I'm not sure if that's the correct way to get the current page URL. Another thing, isn't it too bad to do this on `template_redirect`? I mean, the page is already fetched and then it redirects again if the condition is met, feels like not clean for me.

Comment: So what's your question? Your approach looks fine and the docs for `remove_query_arg` look pretty clear?

Comment: @mozboz -  I decided to try my luck and do it on my own, but still having an issue. Please see the updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need  `$url = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` for getting the current URL to remove the query string.

All you need is `remove_query_arg('the_query', false)`. False, means it will use the current URL and your code can be shorten to:

```
function abc_redirections(){
    if(isset($_GET['query_string']) || isset($_GET['query_string_1'])){
        $array = array();
        if(isset($_GET['query_string']) && (empty($_GET['query_string']) || !is_numeric($_GET['query_string']) || (is_numeric($_GET['query_string']) && $_GET['query_string'] < 1))){
            $array[] = "query_string";
        }
        
        if(isset($_GET['query_string_1']) && (empty($_GET['query_string_1']) || !is_numeric($_GET['query_string_1']) || (is_numeric($_GET['query_string_1']) && $_GET['query_string_1'] < 1))){
            $array[] = "query_string_1";
        }

        wp_redirect(remove_query_arg($array, false));
    }
}
```

Also, you are right. The page will become slow with the current approach since it will load twice.

Comment: It works, however after adding `exit;` after `wp_redirect()` it shows only blank page? Is it okay not to add `exit;`?